# Change MenuItem text in ASP.NET / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP Menu like this:

```
<asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" 
 EnableViewState="False" IncludeStyleBlock="False"
 Orientation="Horizontal" meta:resourcekey="NavigationMenuResource1">
       <Items>
             <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="<% MenuItemResource1 %>" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResource1"/>
             <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Products.aspx" Text="Products" meta:resourcekey="MenuItemResource2" />
       </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

What I want to do, is to change the MenuItem text based on the user language selection (CultureInfo). For example, the "Products" section should be called "Produits" in french.

I added a .resx file for english and french. If I use a < div> element with an Id, this works fine. The problem is that the asp MenuItem doesn't seem to have an ID, so I'm not able to access it. Like the example, I tried to set the first MenuItem text with to a "Resource" item, but when I change the language, the text is not changing.

How can I change that text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    System.Reflection.FieldInfo[] fi = 
    this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | 
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; ++i)
{
    FieldInfo info = fi[i];

    //info can be Button, Menuitem, ToolbarButton.....
    //info.Name returns true name of control
    //        - menuItem1, btnChangelanguage....
    if (typeof(MenuItem) == info.FieldType)
    {
        MenuItem item = (MenuItem)info.GetValue(this);
        item.Text = resources.GetString(info.Name + ".Text");
    }
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14615/Dynamically-changing-menu-items-according-to-Cultu

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the Menu Item Text Dynamically, Try this.

```
Menu1.Items[0].Text="Home"; // For Text
Menu1.Items[0].NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx"; // For Url
```

Answer (score 0):

On page load, you set the text, navigate url

```
NavigationMenu.Items.Add(new MenuItem
        {
            Text = "Your text goes here",
            NavigateUrl = "Your URL goes here"
        });
```